# polymer, using attribute data binding in the constructor functions

Tags: javascript, polymer, chart.js

I'm trying to use a polymer custom element to format and display charts rendered by charts.js - i'm trying to get the custom element `<chart-element>` to pass it's instanced attribute `chartID` to the constructor function to properly create the chart - for the life of me i cant get the `getContext()` method/function to run on anything using the passed attributes

this is the instanced custom element declaration:

```
<chart-element chartID="figure1"></chart-element>
```

and here is my custom element:

```
<polymer-element name="chart-element" attributes="chartID">
  <template>
    <style>...</style>
    <div class="content">
        <canvas id="{{chartID}}" class="pieChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('chart-element', {
        ready: function () {

            var dataFigure1 = [...];

            alert(this.chartID);
            alert(this.$.chartID);
            alert(this.chartID.getContext('2d');

            var canvasElement = this.chartID.getContext("2d");
            alert("canvasElement: "+canvasElement);

            new Chart(canvasElement).Pie(dataFigure1);
        }
   });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

i've tried a million different combinations of the last line to render the chart, but i can't seem to find one that works

`alert(this.chartID);` resolves fine to "figure1" but `new Chart(this.chartID.getContext('2d')).Pie(dataFigure1);` throws an "undefined is not a function" error

`alert(this.$.chartID);` resolves to "undefined"

`alert(this.chartID.getContext('2d');` doesn't resolve at all, or isn't alertable, not surprising

`new Chart(this.$.figure1.getContext('2d')).Pie(dataFigure1);` works fine, but i'm trying to not hard code this line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert(this.chartID)` displays the content of the `chartID` property of your element. This property contains the string *"figure1"*, since this is passed in as the attribute `chartID="figure1"`.

`this.chartID.getContext('2d')` tries to call the function `getContext()` on this string. Since strings don't contain this function, you get an *"undefined is not a function"* error.

`this.$.chartID` is undefined, because the object that is returned by the `$` function contains properties which *keys* are the *ids* of the elements in the element's template. So you can write `this.$.figure1` but not `this.$.chartID` (this only works if you'd written `<canvas id="chartID">`)

Long story short, what you could do is writing `this.$[this.chartID]`. This accesses the element which id is `this.chartID` which in turn is *"figure1"*.

But the question is: why would you want to do this at all. Since the shadow DOM isolates all the DOM in your element from the outside, it doesn't cause any problems if you simply write `<canvas id="chart">`. Even if you instantiate many *chart-elements*, these same ids don't interfere with each other.

Additional note: There is a [Chart.js Polymer element](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/chart-js) in the Polymer-Labs GitHub repository and Rob Dodson has also written some [Chart.js Polymer elements](https://github.com/robdodson/chart-js-polymer).

Comment: So your template would have `<canvas id="chart" class="pieChart"></canvas>` and your `ready` method would be simply `new Chart(this.$.chart.getContext('2d')).Pie(dataFigure1);`.

Comment: thanks @dirk & @cletus, yeah i totally get your suggestion about not worrying about passing div IDs to the custom element and am now rearranging my code for that...  
but now i'm running into a different beast - i still need to pass the `<chart-element>` an attribute to tell which dataSet (array) to use, i'm diving into that now with my new found understanding of what `this` and `this.$` deal with - thanks again

Comment: ok so its all working with `new Chart(this.$.chart.getContext('2d')).Pie(eval(this.chartData))` thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't need an `eval()` for that if you use Polymer's [type hinting](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrhinting). Basically, add `chartData: [],` before your `ready()` method and Polymer will automatically store `this.chartData` as an array.

Comment: already tried going down that sort of path @cletus, `chartData` is an attribute passed in to the `<chart-element>` custom element - i need to evaluate it because it's passed in as a string that references a data array declared in a `ready()` method - the question above doesn't have my updated code to depict all of this now, so it's a bit incomplete from my current iteration - thanks to you guys it is all working now though